# react-dom.development.js:287 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to fetch the current value selected in the drop down by storing it in a variable called result. But it throws me "Uncaught Type Error" every-time I do that.

I have already tried some varied methods by using "onClick" "onChange"

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names: [],
      equipments:[],
      isLoaded: false,
      result: ""
    }

handleChange (event) {
    this.setState({
      result: event.target.value
    })
    console.log("result=" + this.state.result);
  }

render() {

    let {names, equipments} = this.state;

    let options = names.map(name => {
      return {value: name.name, label: name.name};
    })

    let options3 = equipments.map(equip => {
      return {value: equip.value.name, label: equip.value.name};
    })

return (
<Select placeholder="Enter Site Name" onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
              options={options} />
              {this.state.result} <hr />
)}

Expected: should return the name of the selected drop down option.
e.g., BNTOR1245#Name1
```

Answer (score 0):

so this issue got solved:

```
handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected: ${selectedOption.value}`);
```